# Running multiple files from with Scilab program

Tags: scilab

I'm new to Scilab. I have to run the same program with a dozen different input files. Currently I simply uncomment the line and then rerun the program, and change the output file to a new name

```
// Input data file
data_file = 'data1.txt';
//data_file = 'data2.txt';
//data_file = 'data3.txt';
//data_file = 'data4.txt';
//data_file = 'data5.txt';
//data_file = 'data6.txt';
```

etc. another 6 lines

```
// Output data file name
output_data = '/output_files/data1.csv';
```

Is there a way to read in each file (data1.txt, data2.txt...) execute the body of the program and then output a new output file  (data1.csv, data2.csv ...) instead of what I'm doing now, which is running the program and then editing it to use the next file and run again?

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like:

```
for i=1:6
    // Input data file
    data_file=msprintf("data%d.txt",i);
    // Output data file name
    output_data=msprintf("/output_files/data%d.csv",i);
    // exec the body of your script
end
```